# pandoc filter to hide div of a certain class

Tags: python, pandoc

I need to make a filter for pandoc to hide some specific div in my markdown document.
I try to understand how filters works, but I can't understand it.
I try this filters which contains some code I need to use : https://github.com/chdemko/pandoc-latex-environment/blob/master/pandoc_latex_environment.py
but it fails :

```
$ pandoc myFile.md -t json | python3 pandoc_latex_environment.py

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test.py", line 56, in <module>
    main()
  File "test.py", line 53, in main
    toJSONFilters([environment])
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pandocfilters.py", line 76, in toJSONFilters
    altered = reduce(lambda x, action: walk(x, action, format, doc[0]['unMeta']), actions, doc)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pandocfilters.py", line 76, in <lambda>
    altered = reduce(lambda x, action: walk(x, action, format, doc[0]['unMeta']), actions, doc)
KeyError: 0
```

My question is : **how can I make a python filter for pandoc which delete all div with class "hidden".**

Thanks.
Sorry for my bad english.

Comment: I see this is your first question to StackOverflow. I guess people downvoted the question because they'd prefer more proof that you tried to solve this yourself (e.g., you could add the code you wrote so far). Let me point you to some resources which might help you: [panflute](http://scorreia.com/software/panflute/index.html) is an alternative to pandocfilters, [nice intro here](https://lee-phillips.org/panflute-gnuplot/). [Lua filters](https://pandoc.org/lua-filters.html) are an alternative to JSON-based filters. Let us know if you run into problems.

Answer (score 0):

Ok I finally found what was wrong. pandoc introduce a new JSON format which is only compatible with pandocfilters v.1.4+.